# CreditMemo reconciliation through IDS in QuickBooks for Windows

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We are using IDS to fetch all Invoices and their associated financial transactions. The goal is to match up the invoice with all transactions that are taking its balance to zero.

There seem to be 2 IDS objects that cover these transactions:

- [Payment](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Payment)
- [CreditMemo](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/CreditMemo)

While both objects are referencing the `CustomerId`, only the `Payment` references the `Invoice` object.

The `CreditMemo` is not referencing the `Invoice` with which it is associated.

We know there must be some internal reference between `CreditMemo` and `Invoice`, because it is shown under "Related transactions" when viewing the Invoice in QuickBooks.

How can we fetch the association information between a `CreditMemo` and an `Invoice` through IDS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t see the link between invoice and creditmemo in IDS V2. Based on the IDS V3 spec (http://developer.intuit.com/fmsv3spec/index.html), it looks like the linkedtxn will be available when it comes out and hopefully that will show the linked transactions.

You can pull all the CreditMemos - https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/CreditMemo but they do not show the linked transaction back to the invoice like payment does.

You can see if the credit memo has been paid/used or if the creditmemo status is Payable it means the creditmemo is still available.

See this posting https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=86&threadid=18156